# I am trying to make .jks file process automatic

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I have written a script to make the .jks file automatic. But I am having trouble how to answer the prompts in the cmd.
script:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore C:\keystore5.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048  
 - Ahad Paracha /
 - Company /
 - NY    /
 - NY    /
 - US    /
 - yes
```

The prompts are:

```
 Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  - Ahad Paracha /
 - Company /
 - NY    /
 - NY    /
 - US    /
 - yes
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  
Is CN=Ahad Paracha, OU=, O=, L=, ST=, C= correct?
  [no]:
```

It wont answer the other questions just the first one. I am writing that for CMD.

Comment: Isn't it [possible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) to specify all the parameters in the command line without entering anything interactively?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell can pass strings to an interactive prompts:

Example:

```
'help', 'rescan' | diskpart
```

In your case, you could try:

```
'Ahad Paracha', 'Company', 'NY', 'NY', 'US', 'yes' | keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore C:\keystore5.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```